# Django. get_or_create optimization with defer

Tags: django, django-orm

Is there any difference between these queries:

```
category, _ = models.Category.objects.get_or_create(
    title=some_title,
    brick=node_id,
    parent=parent,
)
```

and:

```
category, _ = models.Category.objects.defer('data').get_or_create(
    title=some_title,
    brick=node_id,
    parent=parent,
)
```

?
Where category model looks like this:

```
class Category(Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    brick = models.IntegerField(
        primary_key=True,
    )
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    data = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True) # very large text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works mostly as you would expect.

The defer doesn't select the field when retrieving the object from the db, but notice that even if the field is deferred it is available in the `WHERE` clause of the get query to check if the object has to be created (as one would expect). If the object is not available then a second `INSERT` is issued, inserting all your fields specified in the `get_or_create` method, even the ones you specified eventually in the `defer` call.

The only nuisance is when creating an object that doesn't exist yet and you don't specify in `get_or_create` a field that you `defer`, as in your case, and then try to access this particular field on the created object, generating an additional (third) query to fetch that field from the db (even if we would know that doesn't exists).

```
# Model has fields a and b, b being optional
a, c = Model.objects.defer('b').get_or_create(a=1)  # Two queries, one to get, the second to insert (ignore that sqlite does 3 queries here)
# c is True
# a is now a deferred object
a.a # doesn't hit the db again
a.b # hits the db trying to retrieve the b field
```

If instead you insert that object, without specifying the defer nor the optional field, you don't hit the database a third time trying to fetch that optional field on the created object.

```
# Model has fields a and b, b being optional
a, c = Model.objects.get_or_create(a=1)  # Two queries as before
# c is True
# a is NOT a deferred object
a.a # doesn't hit the db
a.b # no db hit, b being empty
```

a different case would be the one where you load an object with a deferred field and try to save this object, the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/) states that:

> When calling save() for instances with deferred fields, only the loaded fields will be saved. See save() for more details.